# error when i try to obtain content of an iframe using javascript code as shown

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an iframe within the main window named "test_iframe".

I want to access the content of "test_iframe" within a google chrome extension.

I am trying to access the content of this iframe, but I am getting the following error-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null
```

The javascript code I have used is given below-

```
var htmlvar = document.getElementById('test_iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

What is wrong with the code? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

instead of test_iframe in coding try folllwing

```
    <%=txtName.ClientID%>
```

i.e.

```
    var htmlvar = document.getElementById('<%=txtName.ClientID%').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

Comment: hello again, as per your suggestion, i tried it but it gave same error as before...i tried the following --- var htmlvar = document.getElementById('<%=txtName.ClientID%>').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

Comment: instead of txtname you used your test_iframe ?      and you just wanted to access test_iframe content na?

Comment: ok, do you mean i should use <%=test_iframe.ClientID%> ? I will try that if this is what you mean...

Comment: yes, you should specify your variable name instead of txtname.